# Angular 8: Have One Variable Subscribe to another variable in 1 Component class

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

I have two objects in Angular of the same type.

```
 public addressFinalData: AddressMailingData;
 mailingArchive: AddressMailingData[] = [];
```

How do I subscribe to data objects of the same type in 1 component

Want mailingArchive[2] to always subscribing to value of addressFinalData (anytime AddressFinalData changes, MailingArchive should store the value in array number 2).

Comment: from where you are getting addressFinalData values? is it a form or http call

Comment: just some basic data manipulation, I don't want to track the api in anyway or the form, just the variable addressFinalData

Comment: You have to create an Observable of addressFinalData and subscribe to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create observable of AddressMailingData and in the subscription you can change with new value.

```
public addressFinalData = new Subject<AddressMailingData>();
 mailingArchive: AddressMailingData[] = [];

ngOnInit() {
   this.addressFinalData.subscribe(
       (val: any) => {
           this.mailingArchive[2] = val;
        }
   )
}
```

So whenever you are changing the value of addressFinalData, you need to emit that data with next method.

```
this.addressFinalData.next({newData});
```